# Windows Phone - Application Level DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, session, windows-phone-8, timer, dispatchertimer

My Requirement : Need a session timer for every page(Except login page). If timer exceeded 60 seconds with no user actions performed, it should redirect to the login page.

I have successfully done the above requirement for one page with below code snippets.

```
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
        DateTimeOffset startTime;
        DateTimeOffset lastTime;
        DateTimeOffset stopTime;
        int timesTicked = 1;
        int timesToTick = 60; 


        page_load()
        {  
           dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
           dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
           dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
           startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
           lastTime = startTime;
           dispatcherTimer.Start();    
        } 


        private void PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            lastTime = startTime;
            dispatcherTimer.Start();    
        }

       void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
       {
           DateTimeOffset time = DateTimeOffset.Now;
           TimeSpan span = time - lastTime;
           lastTime = time;
           timesTicked++;
           if (timesTicked > timesToTick)
           {
               isTimeOver = true;
               stopTime = time;

               dispatcherTimer.Stop();

               span = stopTime - startTime;
               MessageBox.Show("Login again", "Session Expired", MessageBoxButton.OK);
               NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Login_3.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
           }
       }
```

I need this logic for every pages. As pages are not accessible in custom classes for navigation, I am confused. 
I don't think writing  `dispatcherTimer_Tick` event in every page is good approach.
Could you please anyone advice how we can do this in one code that can be used for every page?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common base class for each page to inherit from and write this code there.

Example:

```
namespace Test
{     
    public class PageBaseWithTimer: PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

        ... //Copied from question

        int timesToTick = 60; 

        PageBase()
        {
            this.Loaded += PageBase_Loaded;
            this.OnManipulationCompleted += PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationCompleted
        }

        private void PageBase_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

             ... //Copied from question

             dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            lastTime = startTime;
            dispatcherTimer.Start();  
        }      

        void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            DateTimeOffset time = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            ... //Copied from question

            MessageBox.Show("Login again", "Session Expired", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Login_3.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            //dispose timer
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            dispatcherTime.Tick -= dispatcherTimer_Tick
            dispatcherTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Inherit the above class in the pages where you require this timer. Remember to dispose timer in base class if its not required, while navigating away.

```
    public partial class PageWithTimer1 : PageBaseWithTimer
    { 
        public PageWithTimer1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }           
    }

   <c:PageBaseWithTimer xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Test"
        x:Class="BBM.UI.Views.PageWithTimer1" 
        ...

   </c:PageBaseWithTimer>
```

Make sure you give the access modifier as `public` for the base class - `PageBaseWithTimer`, to make it available across all pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tried like this, But i got an error like The name "PageBaseWithTimer" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:TEST"
Could you please elaborate the second code snippet?